# Ruby On Rails : Sidekiq : Instance variable @organisation not available in mailer-layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

I have used `sidekiq` and `redis-server` to send email in background..
**Problem**: Its ok when used sync method to send email. i.e.
in `applicants_controller.rb`

```
UserMailer.notify_applicant_assignment(current_assigned_user.id, applicant, workflow_step).deliver
```

However, when I use `delay` method to send email i.e.

in `applicants_controller.rb`

```
UserMailer.delay.notify_applicant_assignment(current_assigned_user.id, applicant, workflow_step)
```

I get the following error `undefined method 'background_color' for nil:NilClass` in `/layouts/user_mailer.html.erb:17:`

Code inside `mailers/user_mailer.rb`

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  default from: CommonConstants::DO_NOT_REPLY_ADDRESS
  layout 'user_mailer'
    def notify_applicant_assignment(user_id, applicant_id, workflow_step_id)
       @user = User.find(user_id)
       @organization = @user.organization
       @applicant = Applicant.find(applicant_id)
       @url = root_url + 'applicants/' + @applicant.id.to_s
       @workflow_step = WorkflowStep.find(workflow_step_id)
       mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Applicant Assigned.')
    end
end
```

Code inside `layouts/user_mailer.html.erb`

```
<body style="background:#f4f4f4;">
<table width="100%" bgcolor="<%= @organization.background_color %>" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table align="center" width="730" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
```

Error I got in sidekiq console

```
2015-03-24T08:58:14Z 5595 TID-cjors WARN: {"retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer", "args"=>["---\n- !ruby/class 'UserMailer'\n- :notify_applicant_assignment\n- - 4\n  - '9'\n  - '9'\n"], "jid"=>"4421abf04e7e6864c7ee9fd8", "enqueued_at"=>1427187124.323067, "error_message"=>"undefined method `background_color' for nil:NilClass", "error_class"=>"ActionView::Template::Error", "failed_at"=>1427187124.3466575, "retry_count"=>4, "retried_at"=>1427187494.9246943}
2015-03-24T08:58:14Z 5595 TID-cjors WARN: undefined method `background_color' for nil:NilClass
2015-03-24T08:58:14Z 5595 TID-cjors WARN: /home/leapfrog/projects/ATS/app/views/layouts/user_mailer.html.erb:17:in `_app_views_layouts_user_mailer_html_erb__235114594899105140_70586860'
/home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
/home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
/home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
/home/leapfrog/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
/
```

Comment: I might be missing something - but how do you provide the ```org_id``` variable?

Comment: check in method if you are getting `@organization = @user.organization`

Comment: sorry, I have mistakenly posted the code I was experimenting on, now I have edited the question.. thanks for giving interest on helping me :)

Comment: In what context is the mailer called?

Comment: mailer is called when `applicant` is assigned to other `user` @mgrim

Comment: Check you are getting `@organization = @user.organization and `try putting this after your notify_applicant_assignment method `handle_asynchronously :notify_applicant_assignment, :run_at => Proc.new { 5.seconds.from_now }`

Comment: I think your looking at the wrong error. It looks like what you posted `bgcolor="<%= @organization.background_color %>>`  is on line 4 not line 17.

Comment: are you setting @organization.background_color in a callback? (e.g. after_save). If so, you can't depend on these getting called if so (idempotent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very possible that the delay extension work differently then you would expect. They are different that the regular async job.

In [the documentation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-extensions), it is clearly stated that:

> I strongly recommend avoiding delaying methods on instances. This stores object state in Redis which can get out of date, causing stale data problems.

I wouldn't be surprised if the delay extension stores the unrendered template and the mail parameters (subject, to, from, etc') rather then calling the method itself for an outdated instance.

Also, please notice that `notify_applicant_assignment` isn't defined as a **class** method (it looks like an instance method), although the [Sidekiq documentation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-extensions) states that delay should be applied to class methods.

> Any **class** method can be delayed via the same methods as above:

I would recommend making the `notify_applicant_assignment` a class method and trying again (notice the **self** in `def self.notify_applicant_assignment` vs. `def notify_applicant_assignment`).

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  default from: CommonConstants::DO_NOT_REPLY_ADDRESS
  layout 'user_mailer'
    def self.notify_applicant_assignment(user_id, applicant_id, workflow_step_id)
       @user = User.find(user_id)
       @organization = @user.organization
       @applicant = Applicant.find(applicant_id)
       @url = root_url + 'applicants/' + @applicant.id.to_s
       @workflow_step = WorkflowStep.find(workflow_step_id)
       mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Applicant Assigned.')
    end
end
```

Alternatively, I would recommend also using the standard async engine in `applicants_controller.rb`:

```
UserMailer.notify_applicant_assignment_async(current_assigned_user.id, applicant, workflow_step)
```

Please let me know how it goes, so I can research some more if there's still a need.

Good luck!